# Func<int,string> returns from Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm learning ASP.Net MVC and read this book Pro ASP.Net MVC4 by Adam Freeman,
There is code that I don't understand.

```
 public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,
                                              PagingInfo pagingInfo,
                                              Func<int, string> pageUrl) {

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++) {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a"); // Construct an <a> tag
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
                tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
                if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                    tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                result.Append(tag.ToString());
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
        }
```

in unit test project I see the code:

```
Func<int, string> pageUrlDelegate = i => "Page" + i;
MvcHtmlString result = myHelper.PageLinks(pagingInfo, pageUrlDelegate)
```

I understand that it's passing the delegate to PageLinks method.

But in the View or in controller, I didn't see any lambda expression such

```
Func<int, string> pageUrlDelegate = i => "Page" + i;
```

The view code is:

```
 <div class="pager">
   @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x}))
  </div>
```

When executed, how come it generates HTML like below for paging:

```
<div class="pager">
   <a class="selected" href="/">1</a><a href="/**Page2**">2</a>
      <a href="/Page3">3</a>
</div>
```

How does it generates "Page{number}" in the method extension, while we're not passing any delegate such as in the view :

```
 Func<int, string> pageUrlDelegate = i => "Page" + i;
```

Thank you for the guidance. 
Regards,
Harry

Comment: that new{page = x} is an annonymous type, that gets passed to Url.Action, this probably accesses the page value using dynamic and formats the output like it is.
Does it make any difference, when you change page to something else?
Also dont you have a method inside your controller called "List" with an int called "page" as parameter?

Comment: CSharpie, Thanks for quick response, there is a List method in controller that accepts int page parameter, and the routeConfig also have the routing that translate Page{} to List method in the controller. What I don't understand is how pageUrl(i) in method extension is able to achieve result "Page{x}" while building the tag, while we don't specify that the string returned  from Func<int,string> = i => "Page " + i.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *are* passing a delegate. The lambda expression is here:

```
x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x})
```

You're not declaring it as a separate variable, but that's nothing special - you could do the same in your unit test:

```
MvcHtmlString result = myHelper.PageLinks(pagingInfo, i => "Page" + i)
```

In both cases you're creating a `Func<int, string>` - it's just that the delegate in the "real" application calls `Url.Action` to create the string from a name and an instance of an anonymous type.

Comment: Jon, Thank you for answering. How does pageUrl(i) in method extension is able to generate result "Page{x}" while building the tag, while we don't specify that the string returned from Func<int,string> = i => "Page " + i in the view?

Comment: @ryman: It's not clear what you mean. The extension method calls the delegate - which in the case of the "real" code calls `Url.Action`. In your sample code it would just return "Page 1" or "Page 2" etc.

Comment: please excuse for my dumbness, in unit test it's clear that it's passing Func<int, string> pageUrlDelegate = i => "Page" + i;  but in "real" application it pass: x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x}) how does the method extension is able to generate "Page 1" while it's not passing  method i => "Page" + i; Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: @ryman: The delegate calls `Url.Action("List", new { page = 1})` (when the `x` parameter has a value of 1). Try making that call yourself, and you'll see how it works. `Url.Action` is just a method call (it's actually an extension method call I believe - `UrlHelper.Action`).

Comment: Thanks for be bare with me :). I modified the paging, in the view so it looks like below : 
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => "Paging" + x))                     
now it generates "Paging1" "Paging2" which I expected to be :). My confusion is in the "real" application we're passing x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x}) which suppose to call controller method named List and pass parameter page, how come the method extension translate it to x => ("Page" + x)?

Comment: @ryman: It sounds like you should ignore the lambda expression part, and just try calling the `UrlHelper.Action` method...

Comment: calling only UrlHelper.Action generates error, CS1501: No overload for method 'PageLinks' takes 1 arguments :(

Comment: @ryman: Well presumably you're calling `PageLinks` inappropriately, but I can't help with that much... I think I was mistaken about `UrlHelper.Action` being an extension method mind you. But you should be able to call `Url.Action("List", new { page = 1 })` for example, where `Url` is a `UrlHelper`.

Comment: yes I can do that: Url.Action("List", new { page = 1 }), but still I don't understand how does the method extension able to generate result "Page " + i in PageUrl method, while in "real" application it pass x=> Url.Action("List", new {page=x}) or Url.Action("List", new {page=1})

Comment: @ryman: Sorry, I don't think we're getting anywhere here. There *isn't* a PageUrl method. There's a *delegate* variable called `pageUrl`, but that's not quite the same thing. It's not clear to me whether you're getting confused by delegates in general, MVC, lambda expressions, or what...

Comment: sorry typo mistake, yes I meant pageUrl delegate variable. The code in the **View** don't pass "Page" + i to the method extension variable _pageUrl_ as it did in unit test. Since it doesn't pass "Page" + i, how come the delegate variable pageUrl return "Page1", "Page2" in the method extension?, perhaps now you more understanding of my confusion. I am trying to learn this up and cacth up all this terminology, Thanks for spending your busy time for new bee like me.

Comment: @ryman: Sorry, I still don't think we're getting anywhere. That's simply what `Url.Action("List", new { page = i }` does, when given a page number `i`. You don't explicitly pass `"Page" + i`, but you call a method instead. Again, I suggest that in some context where you can call `Url.Action` yourself explicitly, you do so and see what it does. The lambda expression is still there in plain sight, but it's calling a method rather than just doing string concatenation.

Comment: I did as you suggested, now I see the correlation. Thank You so much Jon.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, spent some hours to search the answer. So, the answer to your question "How does it generate 'Page{number}' in the method extension" lies in the file SportsStore.WebUI/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs. You can open it and watch the code:
`routes.MapRoute(
        name: null,
        url: "Page{page}",
        defaults: new { Controller = "Product", action = "List" }
      );`

This line of code `url: "Page{page}",` generates Page1, Page2 and etc.